# Can I use Valgrind to analyze which functions in my program are using the most memory?

Tags: function, memory, valgrind, executable, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have been given an executable where I have to analyze its memory usage - specifically which functions are using the most memory.

I have used Valgrind to perform memory leak checks and analyzing how much of the heap is used at a given time, etc. However, I am not sure how to use it to analyze memory by function. I know Callgrind allows me to see which functions are called the most. Is there any way to usee Callgrind (or other Valgrind tools) to see which functions are using the most memory?

Answer (score 1):

Try massif (and massif-visualizer if you can install it).

Valgrind tools are a bit of a sledgehammer for this job, and I would also recommend looking at heaptrack.

https://github.com/KDE/heaptrack